# The '!this' in Function.prototype.softBind

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and i'm Currently reading *'this & Object Prototypes'* of the greate **'You Don't Know JS'** book series.
In Chapter 2 (Softening Binding):

```js
if (!Function.prototype.softBind) {
    Function.prototype.softBind = function(obj) {
        var fn = this,
            curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            bound = function bound() {
                return fn.apply(
                    (!this ||
                        (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
                            this === window) ||
                        (typeof global !== "undefined" &&
                            this === global)
                    ) ? obj : this,
                    curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
                );
            };
        bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
        return bound;
    };
}
```

I dont understand:

```js
(!this || (typeof window !== "undefined" && this === window) || (typeof global !== "undefined"  && this === global)
```

specially the **'!this'**

Thanks

Comment: `!` is `NOT`..Will invert `false/false` value to `true` and vice-versa...

Comment: Well, it means *if `this` is falsey* (`== false`). So, `null`, `undefined`, `false` or such.

Answer (score 4):

So, first recall what [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) does:

> The apply() method calls a function with a given this value and
>   arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).

So, the code you're interested in is being passed as the first argument to `apply`, which means it should return some value of `this`, or something that it call pull a `this` from. Let's break it down:

```
(
  !this ||
  (typeof window !== "undefined" && this === window) || 
  (typeof global !== "undefined" && this === global)
)
```

First, why do we need to compare against `undefined` when checking the `window`/`global` objects? [Because that's what `typeof` will return when a comparison against them is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript).

Now, to understand the code better, you could easily rewrite the above like this:

```
if (!this) {
  // If the local 'this' is a falsey value
  return obj;
} else if (typeof window !== "undefined" && this === window) {
  // If window is defined and 'this' is referencing it
  return obj;
} else if (typeof global !== "undefined" && this === global) {
  // If global is defined and 'this' is referencing it
  return obj;
} else {
  return this;
}
```

So, basically, what all that is doing saying is: if the local `this` context is a falsey value or if it points to either the special `window` and/or `global` objects, pull the `this` context from the passed in `obj`. Otherwise, use the local `this` context.

Comment: Thanks  Matthew very helpful