# Eloquent Javascript: what is `this` in the following example?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Looking into [eloquentjavascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html), in the section of `Objects as interfaces`, there is an example:

(Outside of a function, **this refers to the global scope object.**)

```
(function(exports) {
  var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
               "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

  exports.name = function(number) {
    return names[number];
  };
  exports.number = function(name) {
    return names.indexOf(name);
  };
})(this.weekDay = {});

console.log(weekDay.name(weekDay.number("Saturday")));
// → Saturday
```

What does `this refers to the global scope object` mean? what is the global scope object here (this)? Confused.

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Comment: `window` is the global scope object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript

Comment: In a browser, it's `window`, it's just telling you that `this.weekDay` would be the same as `window.weekDay` in this particular example.

Comment: @adeneo how about in backend?

Comment: @BAE probably **global**

Comment: When you run this script in the browser, the global scope is `window`, otherwise, in other evironments (such as node) where there is no `window`, it refers to a global object, accessible from anywhere.