# Capture "this" value in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently running into the following bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208775

Long story short, I need to access `this.browser` instead of `window.browser`. If I replace my webpack generated file with `console.log(this.browser)` I get the correct window variable, whereas if I access `window.browser` I get undefined. The suggested fix is to access `this.browser`, but I'm unsure of how to do that as a webpack module:

I have a simple browser.js file which I use to export the browser info:

```
export default window.chrome || window.browser || this.browser;
```

Because we're in a function context, both `window.browser` and `this.browser` are undefined, as well as `window.chrome` (As I'm developing this in firefox). How would I go about accessing `this.browser` (this being in the global scope) through webpack?

Comment: How about `export default chrome || browser` for global variables? (Potentially with `typeof` checks)

Comment: @Bergi Create this into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Dunno, it's just a workaround. The actual question - how to access the global object using `this` inside a webpacked (and babel-transpiled?) module - still stands.

Comment: @Bergi Accessing `browser` without any modifiers (`this` or `window`) appears to return exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in the top level scope of a script execution context (as opposed to a module context) is nothing other than the [global object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-global-object). The global object in webpages is the `window` object, but in other environments (e.g. node.js, web workers or webextensions) it can be some other object. In the case of webextensions it is an object that has a [security proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Xray_vision) delegating to the unsafe window object as its prototype.

So, since top level `this` is the global object the problem boils down to getting the global object, for which there is the [indirect `eval` approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript)
Small caveat: To use eval in a of webextensions you'll have to [relax the extension CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) in the manifest.

To summarize the current object relations in webextensions:

top level `this` is the global object.

`this.prototype` is a security proxy to the untrusted window that gives a pristine view on the standard window properties. Due to how variable lookups work and the self-referential nature of `window.window` it's also `this.window` via prototype lookup and unqualified `window` via delegation to the global object when no local variables exist

`unsafeWindow == window.wrappedJSObject` is the target of the security proxy, which is the window object and global of the untrusted webpage itself

Comment: Given the OP talks of webpack, he might be using ES6 modules, where the "top level" module scope does not have that `this` value. +1 on indirect `eval` though, that should always work

Comment: @Bergi considering the bug he is linking to and the `console.log` example it must be the script top level `this`. If he were referring to the module top level `this` he would be getting an undefined error anyway which would be unrelated to the issue.