# How to require plugins once and access it globally?

Tags: javascript, plugins, nativescript, require

My app was made before the Nativescript CLI v5.x and got to a point where I needed to update CLI versions. The CLI version 5.4.2 suggests to add "tns-core-modules/" for every 'require' I have in my app since short import is deprecated in v5.2.0, since I have tons of plugins required on tons of pages, it's quite a pain in the ass changing every require line. How can I require all my plugins once and then use them on every page or anywhere I need it?

Comment: You only need to change the require statements for short-imports to 'tns-core-modules' stuff. Yes that can be much. But you don't need to change **every require** for **every plugin**.

Comment: yes I know. and I did it before asking my question. All I want is a way to prevent  repercussions like this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you have access to an `object` that always exists in the global scope, this global object provides variables and functions, the goal is to add your library to it.
You have the `window` object for example in a browser.

Find the global object (look post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript)) on your project and add your library to this object like :

```
var myLib = require('myLib');

var globalObject = Function('return this')();
globalObject.myLib = myLib;
```