# How can I make my JavaScript library global?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a JavaScript library and have it readily available everywhere, exactly as `Moment.js` does.
For example, when I import `Moment.js` I can use it wherever I want by just typing:

```
moment.someMomentFunction()
```

Similarly, I'd want to call my function from everywhere by just doing:

```
mylib.function1()

mylib.function2()

etc..
```

Looking at the `Moment.js` source code I cannot see any reference to the `window` object (which is the one you should use if you want your object to be global)

Comment: `window.mylib=mylib;` - add it to `window`

Comment: _"I cannot see any reference to the window object..."_ Because they do it like this --> `moment = this.moment` , will create a global `moment` instance [Source](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2e2a5b35439665d4b0200143d808a7c26d6cd30f/meteor/export.js)

Comment: @hanshenrik ok but I just said no window object is being used. I think Ramiz Wachtler nailed it

Comment: Simple `var mylib = …` (in global scope) or `mylib = …` (in sloppy mode) assignments do create global variables without needing a `window` reference.

Comment: @RamizWachtler great, let me try that...

Comment: Actually, at Moment.js site you can see that global `moment` is deprecated. So, just as they do, you need to bind it manually

Comment: @RamizWachtler tried the mylib = this.mylib and it didn't work. mylib is not visible everywhere

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini, just get the global (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript) and assign your object to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: If you specifically want to create a library, [export / import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) should help you:

```
import * as myModule from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Export a function in the library with the export keyword:

```
export function bing(Parameters here) {
alert("bong");
}
```

---

As answered in [Calling a javascript function in another js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file)

You can only call functions from files that were loaded before and are in the same scope. If the accepted answer from the refered post doesn't work, try jQuery

`$.getScript(url, function() {
bläh();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary I use something like this to define a separate module using ES5.

```
LibName= window.LibName || {};

LibName = function () {

  var yourVar1;
  var yourVar2;


  publicFunc1 = function() {

  };

  privateFunc2 = function() {

  };


  return {
    "publicFuncName" :  publicFunc1
  }

}();
```

With the help of ES6, you may create with class and without window variable.

```
class MyLib {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 1;
    this.bar = 2;
  }

  myPublicMethod1() {
    return this.foo;
  }

  myPublicMethod2(foo) {
    return foo + this.bar;
  }
}

const instance = new MyLib();
export { instance as MyLib };
```

In code, you going to use it like this

```
import { MyLib } from './MyLib';
```