# Multiple textareas into one text file

Tags: javascript, html, saving-data

I wanted to ask how can I write multile text areas into a html and then connect them into the javascript, because I was able just to connect one. My idea is that the first text area will be for one information and the second for another. This information will be than combine in the text file that the website will export.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script>

        function saveDynamicDataToFile() {

            var userInput = document.getElementById("myText").value;
            
            var blob = new Blob([userInput], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
            saveAs(blob, "code.txt");
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <button type="button" class="BuyBtn2" style="background-color: blueviolet; margin-right: 40px;" onclick="saveDynamicDataToFile();">Click to Save</button>
    </header>

    <textarea id="myText" hidden></textarea>
    <textarea id="myText" hidden></textarea>
</body>
</html>

plus here is the FileSaver file 

    /*
    * FileSaver.js
    * A saveAs() FileSaver implementation.
    *
    * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
    *
    * License : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md (MIT)
    * source  : http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js
    */
    
    // The one and only way of getting global scope in all environments
    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277182/1008999
    var _global = typeof window === 'object' && window.window === window
      ? window : typeof self === 'object' && self.self === self
      ? self : typeof global === 'object' && global.global === global
      ? global
      : this
    
    function bom (blob, opts) {
      if (typeof opts === 'undefined') opts = { autoBom: false }
      else if (typeof opts !== 'object') {
        console.warn('Deprecated: Expected third argument to be a object')
        opts = { autoBom: !opts }
      }
    
      // prepend BOM for UTF-8 XML and text/* types (including HTML)
      // note: your browser will automatically convert UTF-16 U+FEFF to EF BB BF
      if (opts.autoBom && /^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(blob.type)) {
        return new Blob([String.fromCharCode(0xFEFF), blob], { type: blob.type })
      }
      return blob
    }
    
    function download (url, name, opts) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open('GET', url)
      xhr.responseType = 'blob'
      xhr.onload = function () {
        saveAs(xhr.response, name, opts)
      }
      xhr.onerror = function () {
        console.error('could not download file')
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
    
    function corsEnabled (url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      // use sync to avoid popup blocker
      xhr.open('HEAD', url, false)
      try {
        xhr.send()
      } catch (e) {}
      return xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299
    }
    
    // `a.click()` doesn't work for all browsers (#465)
    function click (node) {
      try {
        node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
      } catch (e) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 80,
                              20, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
        node.dispatchEvent(evt)
      }
    }
    
    // Detect WebView inside a native macOS app by ruling out all browsers
    // We just need to check for 'Safari' because all other browsers (besides Firefox) include that too
    // https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/macos
    var isMacOSWebView = _global.navigator && /Macintosh/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /AppleWebKit/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)
    
    var saveAs = _global.saveAs || (
      // probably in some web worker
      (typeof window !== 'object' || window !== _global)
        ? function saveAs () { /* noop */ }
    
      // Use download attribute first if possible (#193 Lumia mobile) unless this is a macOS WebView
      : ('download' in HTMLAnchorElement.prototype && !isMacOSWebView)
      ? function saveAs (blob, name, opts) {
        var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
        var a = document.createElement('a')
        name = name || blob.name || 'download'
    
        a.download = name
        a.rel = 'noopener' // tabnabbing
    
        // TODO: detect chrome extensions & packaged apps
        // a.target = '_blank'
    
        if (typeof blob === 'string') {
          // Support regular links
          a.href = blob
          if (a.origin !== location.origin) {
            corsEnabled(a.href)
              ? download(blob, name, opts)
              : click(a, a.target = '_blank')
          } else {
            click(a)
          }
        } else {
          // Support blobs
          a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href) }, 4E4) // 40s
          setTimeout(function () { click(a) }, 0)
        }
      }
    
      // Use msSaveOrOpenBlob as a second approach
      : 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' in navigator
      ? function saveAs (blob, name, opts) {
        name = name || blob.name || 'download'
    
        if (typeof blob === 'string') {
          if (corsEnabled(blob)) {
            download(blob, name, opts)
          } else {
            var a = document.createElement('a')
            a.href = blob
            a.target = '_blank'
            setTimeout(function () { click(a) })
          }
        } else {
          navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(bom(blob, opts), name)
        }
      }
    
      // Fallback to using FileReader and a popup
      : function saveAs (blob, name, opts, popup) {
        // Open a popup immediately do go around popup blocker
        // Mostly only available on user interaction and the fileReader is async so...
        popup = popup || open('', '_blank')
        if (popup) {
          popup.document.title =
          popup.document.body.innerText = 'downloading...'
        }
    
        if (typeof blob === 'string') return download(blob, name, opts)
    
        var force = blob.type === 'application/octet-stream'
        var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(_global.HTMLElement) || _global.safari
        var isChromeIOS = /CriOS\/[\d]+/.test(navigator.userAgent)
    
        if ((isChromeIOS || (force && isSafari) || isMacOSWebView) && typeof FileReader !== 'undefined') {
          // Safari doesn't allow downloading of blob URLs
          var reader = new FileReader()
          reader.onloadend = function () {
            var url = reader.result
            url = isChromeIOS ? url : url.replace(/^data:[^;]*;/, 'data:attachment/file;')
            if (popup) popup.location.href = url
            else location = url
            popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
        } else {
          var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          if (popup) popup.location = url
          else location.href = url
          popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
          setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(url) }, 4E4) // 40s
        }
      }
    )
    
    _global.saveAs = saveAs.saveAs = saveAs
    
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
      module.exports = saveAs;
    }
```

Comment: so what's the issue/error that you are facing?

Comment: is it because of this `<textarea id="myText" hidden></textarea>
    <textarea id="myText" hidden></textarea>` ? can you try different `id` ?

Comment: it would be easier if you could trim your code a bit

Answer (score 1):

From your given code I can see you are using same `id` for both the textarea fields, id's in HTML must be unique.

Use `class` to refer the textarea fields instead `id`.

```
    <textarea class="myText" hidden></textarea>
    <textarea class="myText" hidden></textarea>
```

Then you can use either `document.querySelectorAll(".myText")` or `document.getElementsByClassName("myText")` to select textarea fields.