# Create object from string

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a new object using a string?
For example, how can I convert the string "product" to `var p = new Product`?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

What I want to do is to have a menu with `<a href="#home"></a><a href="#products">products</a>` and create the corresponding object from the href each time.

Comment: what do you hope to do with it?

Comment: What's the rule to convert `product` to `var p = new Product`? I can understand `new Product`, but why `p`?

Comment: @chchrist: That sounds dangerous, especially if the string comes from the user... why do you think that is this a good idea? Have you considered any alternative approaches?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiate a JavaScript Object Using a String to Define the Class Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you know the context, yes. Let's say you're in a browser environment and `Person` is a global constructor. Because any global variable is a property of the global object, it means you can access to `Person` through the global object `window`:

```
var p = new Person()
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var p = new window.Person()
```

So you can use the square bracket notation:

```
var p = new window["Person"]();
```

Of course this is valid for every kind of object. If you don't want pollute the global scope, you can have:

```
var mynamespace = {};

mynamespace.Person = function Person() {..}

var p = new mynamespace["Person"]();
```

Comment: That's a much nicer solution than mine +1

Comment: I've tried to create an object using new window["Namespace.MyClass"](), but looks like it's not working. How can we create objects when class contains in modules?

Comment: @NarendraV try new window["Namespace"]["MyClass"]() ? (This is just a guess, I don't know that this will work)

Comment: @NarendraV, you can use the square bracket notation instead of dot notation, not both: you basically tried to get a property named "Namespace.MyClass" from window where what you were looking was get `Namespace` from window, and then from `Namespace`, `MyClass`. @MattFellows shown the proper way to do so. You can also create a function like: `function getReference(string, root) { root = root || this; return string.split(".").reduce(function(ref, item) { return ref[item] }, root) };`, and use as `var o = new getReference("Namespace.MyClass")()`. it's a very simple one, you can make it better.

Answer (score 7):

Well you could always use the hideously insecure and illadvised eval().
e.g.

```
var myStr = "Product"
var p = eval("new " + myStr + "()");
```

or that might be:

```
var myStr = "Product"
eval("var p = new " + myStr + "()");
```

But it's fraught with potential vulnerabilities, especially if the string is coming from user input.

Comment: try searching for "use strict" for eval

Comment: This could be much better solved with a `name -> constructor function` map.

Comment: @FelixKling  I wish there was an example of the name->constructor function map

Comment: @slashdottir: `var constructorMap = {Product: Product}; var p = new constructorMap[myStr]();`

Comment: @FelixKling oic ty

Answer (score 1):

Just another implementation:

```
var nameOfThang = 'Person';
var nameOfThingzName = 'The Dude';

var thangs = { Person: {name: 'Legowski'}, Cars: {} };
var person  = new (eval(thangs[nameOfThang].constructor))();
person.name = new (eval(thangs.Person.name.constructor))(nameOfThingzName) .toString();

console.log('@thang, #Person', person);
```