# How can I create a dynamic JavaScript constructor name determined at runtime?

Tags: javascript

The issue I have is that I am trying to construct an object in JavaScript, but I don't know what the object will be until runtime.

My code looks something like this:

```
var modelType = attrs.type;
return new modelType();
```

attrs.type will contain the name of a valid constructor. So for instance, it might be book, cat or dog. Depending on whatever it is, I want to construct that object. I cannot test what attrs.type is first and then choose the correct constructor because the types might change at any time in the future.

Currently the error I am getting is: Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function. (Since modelType is a string...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do `return new this[modelType]();`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803947/create-object-from-string