# How to get data type from string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, types

I have a few strings

```
strings = [
    "String",
    "Object",
    "Boolean"
]
```

and I would like to use them to declare new objects

```
for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
    var x = new strings[i];
}
```

but instead I get this error:

```
TypeError: string is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/path/code.js)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/path/code.js)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

How can I treat strings as their underlying types?

---

Aside:

I know that I could do something like

```
type_map = {
    String: String,
    Object: Object,
    Boolean: Boolean
}
```

and then go

```
for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
    var x = new type_map[strings[i]];
}
```

which works, but I'm looking for something slightly more elegant if it exists.

Comment: `"String"` is a literal, you cannot instantiate a literal.

Comment: Right, Perhaps I'm not phrasing this correctly, but what I'm trying to find out if there is some way to get the literal from the String string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create object from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803947/create-object-from-string)

Comment: "new" can be used only on function, not on string. All global variables are elements of "window", so window["String"] corresponds to global function String.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with the obvious?

```
var i, x, constructors = [
    String,
    Object,
    Boolean
];

for(i = 0; i < constructors.length; i++){
    x = new constructors[i];
}
```

Bear in mind that anything in JS is an object (including "class names") and may be used, pretty much, however you want.

Answer (score 1):

The constructors for these classes are properties of the global object.

For example, in a browser, you could do

```
console.log(window['String'] === String); // true
var str = new window[strings[0]]();
console.log(str); // ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a great way to do it with the [eval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
strings = [
    "String",
    "Object",
    "Boolean"
]

for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
    var x = new (eval(strings[i]));
}
```

so to summarize `eval("String") === [Function: String]`

Comment: Actually I think you found the one *wrong* way to do it. Please consider the other options before going to the `eval`, as you will spoil yourself with bad pratices.

Comment: @BatScream Yeah, there's technically no problem. The eval will evaluate just the string and return the function contained in the object with the name specified by the string. Then will apply the function as a constructor on the context created by `new`.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru -Thanks for the explanation. Got a clear picture. There is a syntax error there though i think. `new (eval(strings[i]))`

Comment: Much better to use Alin's solution than using `eval()` as `eval()` is slow and generally something to shy away from unless there is no other solution, but usually, there is another solution.

Comment: @BatScream It seems so. The new operator is implemented a bit differently than I imagined, but the error can be circumvented with some custom operator priorities: `new (eval(strings[i]))`. Disclaimer: This comment is just for sport, please don't use this code in software development.