# Create object using window[class name]

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a class like this

```
"use strict";

class Person {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

And I'd like to create a `Person` using window like this:

```
var bob = new window["Person"](0, 15);
```

Like done here: [Instantiate a JavaScript Object Using a String to Define the Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name)

or here: [Create object from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803947/create-object-from-string)

But it's not working. I get the error:`Uncaught TypeError: window.Person is not a function`

Is this not possible or am I making a stupid mistake?

Comment: Are you transpiling with Babel? You likely need to manually attach `Person` to `window`. (Also, why would you do this?)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. See [working JSBin](https://jsbin.com/duwimi/edit?js,console).

Comment: See the possible duplicate [Create object from string in JavasScript ECMAScript 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31776949/1048572) for how to do it properly. If that helped, I'll close.

Comment: Yes @Bergi, I don't know what babel is but I'm guessing that's what I'm messing up. You can close it, thanks for your help.

Comment: To explain the issue: `class`, `let` and `const` don't create a property on the global object (like `var` does).