# Angular2 typescript create new object dynamically with class name from variable?

Tags: javascript, class, typescript

I tried to get to work some sort of:

```
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor() {

    let className: string = "TheClass";

    /* should be the same as .. = new TheClass() */
    let superSpecial = new className();

  }

}
```

I have not yet figured out how to do this? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Be aware that you can't just do this out of the box. You'll need to store your classes in a collection of some sort and then reference them.

Comment: This is more of a javascript question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803947/create-object-from-string

Comment: What you are looking for is a "factory"; google for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. If your class is in a separate module:

**SomeClass.ts**

```
export class SomeClass {

    constructor(arg: string) {
        console.log(arg);
    }
}
```

**App.ts**

```
import * as s from "./SomeClass";

var instance = new s["SomeClass"]("param");
```

---

Or using namespaces:

```
namespace Test {

    export class SomeClass {

        constructor(arg: string) {
            console.log(arg);
        }
    }
}

var instance = new Test["SomeClass"]("param");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor() {

    // suppose TheClass is the imported class name you want to instantiate
    let className: typeof TheClass = TheClass;

    /* should be the same as .. = new TheClass() */
    let superSpecial = new className(); // you "new" it as normal

  }
```

Comment: Please check my new answer, definitely gonna work for ya this time

Comment: His question centers around creating an instance based on a string.  This doesn't answer that.

Answer (score -2):

You should use square bracket notation:

```
const classNameStr = 'example';
const myStore = {example: class {}};
const init = new myStore[classNameStr]();
// Or in case you class si global
const classNameStr = 'example';
(window as any).example = class {}; // if your class is already global this line should be deleted. I have put it here just to make the example work
const init = new window[classNameStr]();
```

Or Eval:

```
eval(`new ${className}()`);
```

Comment: your first example will not work, the second example will only work if `TheClass` is a global constructor

Comment: Stop referring to thiings in the global namespace using `window`. In fact, stop keeping things in the global namespace altogether.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm not suggesting to use window. I'm only showing how to access it in case it's already present in it. For example in case of native classes ( AudioContext, Audio, ecc.).