# How to convert a string to an object?

Tags: javascript

I preload load two different images at the top of my javascript file.

```
var imgColor = new Image();
var imgLoadedColor = false;
imgColor.src = 'color/progress.png';

imgColor.onload = function(){
  imgLoadedColor = true;
}   

var imgBlackWhite = new Image();
var imgLoadedColor = false;
imgBlackWhite.src = 'blackWhite/progress.png';

imgBlackWhite.onload = function(){
  imgLoadedColor = true;
}
```

The string in `this.options.type` is either `imgColor` or `imgBlackWhite`.

When I try to pass the argument `this.options.type` to a function, I get an error because the value in `this.options.type` is a string, not an object.  However if I pass the argument `imgColor` it loads the colored image and if I pass the argument `imgBlackWhite` it loads the black and white image because `imgColor` and `imgBlackWhite` are objects.

How do I create a reference to the objects `imgColor` and `imgBlackWhite` from the value of the string in `this.options.type`?

Comment: Need more code. What does the function your passing `this.options.type` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use an if statement?

```
if (arg == "imgColor") return imgColor;
else return imgBlackWhite;
```

EDIT:  you can also use new windowtypename to instantiate an object (per this thread: [Instantiate a JavaScript Object Using a String to Define the Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name)).  So, instead of the above:

```
return new window[arg]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument:

```
this[this.options.type]
```