# Dynamic varname, avoid eval()

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to create a new instance of a class whose name is dynamically built by:

```
eval('SomeObject.'+id+' = new SomeClass'+Data.type+'(id, Data);');
// results in:
SomeObject._123 = new SomeClassWithDynamicName(id, Data);
```

it works fine, but i'd rather avoid the usage of eval (its almost impossible to track errors in code after an eval occured) and do something like this:

```
SomeObject[id] = new ('SomeClass'+Data.type)(id, Data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var SomeObject[id] = window['SomeClass'+Data.type];
SomeObject[id].setId(id);
SomeObject[id].setData(Data);
```

UPDATE : You can also try this if you don't have setters:

```
var SomeObject[id] = window['SomeClass'+Data.type](id, Data);
```

There is a similar question here : [Instantiate a JavaScript Object Using a String to Define the Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name)

Comment: You're welcome, can you make the question as checked please ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to declare the classes globally as such?  This would be a non-issue if you could register them on an object, like:

```
var classes = {};
classes.Type1 = function (id, data) { ... }
classes.Type2 = function (id, data) { ... }

var type = 'Type1';
var instance = new classes[type](id, data);
```