# Dynamic Factory Method - Instantiate Class by String gets receives error TS2322: Type 'Util' is not assignable to type 'void'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to instantiate classes via configuration with a utility method that looks like this.

```
Util.newClassByName('MyClass')
```

It seems that the code works as far as instantiating my class, but I get a Typescript error that I'm not sure how to resolve.

> app\scripts\scraper\util.ts(18,20): error TS2322: Type 'Util' is not assignable to type 'void'.

My helper methods which is based on code I found via [instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name), is written in TypeScript.

**If I put :void into the method name, I get the error that you see on line 18**

```
class Util {

    public static newClassByName(className): void {
        var namespaceSegment = className.split(".");

        var fn = (window || this);

        for (var i = 0, len = namespaceSegment.length; i < len; i++) {
            fn = fn[namespaceSegment[i]];
        }

        if (typeof fn !== "function") {
            throw new Error("function not found");
        }

        return new fn();   // <-- Line 18
    };
}
```

**If I REMOVE :void from the method then I get this error on the calling code**

```
var scraper = Util.newClassByName(config.scraper);
```

> app\scripts\scraper\scraper-util.ts(68,23): error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.

```
class Util {

    public static newClassByName(className) {
        var namespaceSegment = className.split(".");

        var fn = (window || this);

        for (var i = 0, len = namespaceSegment.length; i < len; i++) {
            fn = fn[namespaceSegment[i]];
        }

        if (typeof fn !== "function") {
            throw new Error("function not found");
        }

        return new fn();
    };
}
```

Comment: because your function has a return type of `void`?

Comment: for clarity, I have expanded my problem because originally I did not have the void and typescript was delivering a different error message, which I have now included

Comment: If you do `new Util.newClassByName()` and in that function `return new fn()`, you're `new`ing twice.

Comment: I noticed that as well and rectified without resolution

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this:

```
class Scraper {
    constructor(myProp: number) {
        this.MyProp = myProp;
    }
    public MyProp: number;
    public MyFunc = () => console.log(this.MyProp);
}

var config = {
    scraper: "the.correct.namespace.here"
}

window["the"] = {
    "correct": {
        "namespace": {
            "here": Scraper
        }
    }
}

class Util {
    public static getClassByName<T>(className): { new (...args: any[]): T } {
        var namespaceSegment = className.split(".");

        var fn = (window || {});

        for (var i = 0, len = namespaceSegment.length; i < len; i++) {
            fn = fn[namespaceSegment[i]];
            if (fn === undefined) {
                throw new Error("class not found");
            }
        }

        if (typeof fn !== "function") {
            throw new Error("class not found");
        }

        return fn as { new (...args: any[]): T };
    }
}

var myScraperClass = Util.getClassByName<Scraper>(config.scraper)
var scraper = new myScraperClass(23);
scraper.MyFunc();
```

Here we use the newable interface `{ new (...args: any[]): T }` together with some generics to let you define the type of the resulting object.

Comment: Whilst this looks like it is in the right direction, unfortunately this code did not work, I tried to get it working over last hour, but I'm not fully conversant with generics in typescript, so I'm a little lost, I tried to get a working test JSFiddle/JSBin of this as well, but none of these tools are all that good with typescript

Comment: This code works in [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) as long as window.config.scraper is properly initialized. `type Scraper { ... }` will not do it, you have to replace it with something like `class Scraper {
    MyProp: number;
};

(<any>window).config = {
    scraper: Scraper
}`

Comment: @DavidCruwys I'm sorry, of course I've should have given you an executable example. I've edited my answer.