# ES 6 dynamically work on class after definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I was previously rolling my own Javascript OOP but now I'm playing with `ES6` and want to use the class **defined** after **definition** in a generic way.

**Note**
Any answer with `new` in it is not what I'm after.

Pseudo code:

```
// base.js
class Base {
    constructor(arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    // This is the behaviour I'm after
    //afterDefined(cls) {
    afterExtended(cls) {    // probably a better name
        console.log(`Class name ${cls.prototype.name}`);
    }
}

// frombase.js
class FromBase extends Base {
    constructor({ p1='val1', p2='val2'} = {}) {
        super(...arguments);
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
}
```

The output in the console should be:

```
'Class name FromBase'
```

So far the only solution I have come up with is to have a static method on `Base` and call it after the class declaration when I define a new class but I will most likely forget to do this more than once.

Just to be really thorough on why I don't like the static solution; it will force me to import `Base` in every single file.

Example using a static method (which I don't want) https://jsfiddle.net/nL4atqvm/:

```
// base.js
class Base {
    constructor(arg) {
        super(...arguments);
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    // This is the behaviour I'm after
    static afterExtended(cls) {
        console.log(`Class name ${cls.name}`);
    }
}

// frombase.js
class FromBase extends Base {
}
// just after defining the FromBase class
Base.afterExtended(FromBase);
```

Comment: wouldn't a call to `super()` do it?

Comment: @Icepickle Check out the fiddle. I'm not instantiating anything.

Comment: So instead the name of `afterDefined` would rather be `afterExtend`. And you want `afterExtend` to be called automatically if another class is defined that extends from `Base`. Right?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. There are no public hooks triggered when subclassing another class.

Comment: I agree with @nils but further more, I don't have a clue why you want to implement this behavior. Why do you want to have this level of control? It doesn't make lots of sense from my point of view. What problem are you really trying to tackle here?

Comment: For some reason there is no universal way of enumerating classes defined. Running this generically would make it possible to populate a singleton class with class names and constructors automagically. It would make creating classes dynamically quite easy since all I ever pass is an object anyway and the constructor sets all defaults.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Exactly!

Comment: Closest I could get to, is using a proxy on  the Base class, but this won't give you proper naming (it would however trigger on each extend), as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nL4atqvm/1/)

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks. I'll check that out and do some more digging.

Comment: I doubt it will do you any good, this is a terribly expensive way to do what you want to do...

Comment: Roger that. I'll just check the Proxy out for good measure :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no javascript built-in trigger that is calling a method on a class when a subclass is defined that extends from it.

Because you're rolling your own library, you could craft some kind of method the creates and returns a new class that extends a given base class. Maybe check out this answer that may help how to define your classes: [Instantiate a JavaScript Object Using a String to Define the Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name)

You could also check how other javascript libraries creates (sub)classes. For example, Ext JS has a ClassManager that you could look into.

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.ClassManager.html (docs)
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/src/ClassManager.js.html (source)

When this question would be about instantiation and not about defining classes, I would say:

```
afterDefined(cls) {
    console.log(`Class name ${this.constructor.name}`);
}
```

Usage:

```
let x = new FromBase()
x.afterDefined() // --> Class name FromBase
```

To get the name of the class, use

```
static afterDefined(cls) {
    console.log(`Class name ${this.name}`);
}
```

Comment: I want after definition and not after initialization

Comment: @Asken And also the moment Base is extended into something else?

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to the punch @ChristiaanWesterbeek :)

Comment: @zv_ No punch yet struck so keep on fighting ;)

Comment: Did punch struck now?

Comment: No, I still need to call it and I don't want that.

Comment: ExtJS uses the ClassManager based on `Ext.define` as far as I know/remember (been a while), I don't think it has anything to do with ES6

Comment: Yeah, I don't think they'll go for ES6 anytime soon either. My previous implementation was based on the ancient John Resig implementation with an added dose of dynamic generation to it and just the "afterDefined" was one of them which works pretty much like ExtJS does. It's annoying to have had the power and lost it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
class Base {
    constructor(arg) { this.arg = arg; }

    static afterDefined(cls) {
        console.log(`Class name ${this.constructor.name}`);
    }
}

Base = new Proxy(Base, {
    get: function(target, key, receiver) {
        if (typeof target == 'function' && key == 'prototype' && target.name == Base.name) {
            Reflect.apply(Base.afterDefined, Reflect.construct(class FromBase {}, []), [])
        }
        return target[key];
    }
});

class FromBase extends Base {}
```

In order for this to load class names, you will have to embed or forward-declare that information inside of the Proxy `receiver` *prior* to extending from it (which means you either need to enumerate ahead of time which classes you'll be inheriting to *or* to have some function call just prior to that class's declaration).

There are a bunch of other neat total hacks in the same vein such as looking at the source (text) of the file that you just loaded JavaScript from and then parsing that text as if it were JavaScript (people have used this to write Scheme interpreters that can accept new code inside of `<script>` tags).

If you are a library author intending to target Node, there are *even more* ways to go about doing this.

Comment: but you are assigning the constructor with `FromBase` in your `const klass` construction, is that what you want?

Comment: @Icepickle The constructor being assigned to `klass` is just a function named `FromBase`, the *real* `FromBase` isn't built by the time that line is run.

As to why the constructor should be assigned to a fake function, the idea there is that the `receiver` can use that information in the scheme described above.

Comment: Although I suggested the proxy option in the comments, I really doubt this is a useful approach. I think your answer is inventive, but you are just replacing the call to the method with defining stuff in the proxy, which honestly, I think, doesn't really change things for the future. Lets say you make now a second class, how would your code change?

Comment: @Asken *"In order for this to load class names, you have to embed or forward declare that information inside of the Proxy receiver class prior to extending from it"*

Comment: Any chance you can uodate the code with 2 classes to see how that might work zv_?

Comment: @Icepickle You create a new proxy object or define a getter on `window`/`Base` for each superclass. If you are on Node you can use `Module._load` to generate these dynamically without making a new proxy object for each subclass (you might be able to do it on the browser with `eval` as well).  Either way, you are totally correct that this is *not* good code and would be a huge footgun of an OOP library if implemented.

Comment: But I think@Asken rather wants to know about multiple subclasses, not superclasses.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It should work with any subclass.

Answer (score -1):

```
// base.js

class Base {
constructor(arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
}

// This is the behaviour I'm after
afterDefined(cls) {
        console.log(`Class name ${cls}`);
    }
}


// frombase.js
class FromBase extends Base {
    constructor(arg) {
        super(arg)
    }
}


let f = new FromBase();
f.afterDefined('text');//this you text or object
```

have to be aware of is. file loading order, `super` is an instance of the parent class. good luck.