# How to create the instance of the class by its string name? I tried to use `window` for these purposes also.

Tags: javascript

JS6, Browser

How to create the instance of the class by its string name? For example I have a string `Foo` and I need to create an instance of `Foo` class. I don't want to write such construction:

```
let className = getClassName(); // returns 'Foo', `Stuff` or other
...
let item = null;

if(`Foo` == className){
  item = new Foo();
}
else if(`Stuff` == className){
  item = new Stuff();
}
```

**UPD**

I try to get access to my class constructor through the `window` object but I have the problem: it returns `undefined`. But my class exists and browser knows it:

[image]

Comment: is it browser javascript, or nodejs?

Comment: Try `new window['className']()` if it's running in a browser context.

Comment: this is browser javascript

Comment: You are probably looking for factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is what you should do, in my opinion. This is a standard way of instantiating objects when the type of object is known at runtime, and is called the Factory Method Pattern.

You should avoid duplicating this everywhere in your code by using a factory object that will encapsulate the object creation. This factory object will have a method that will take the type name as its parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Please use google: [Instantiate a JavaScript Object Using a String to Define the Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name)

```
var myObject = window[classNameString];
```

P.S. I copy pasted your title of question and added javascript in front.

Comment: Do not answer duplicates, mark them as duplicates.

Comment: I added the `UPD` section. Look it, please.

Comment: You need the word `new` in front or it will return the class, rather than an instance.

Comment: https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/08/2fe232334810ee26abdccd9ce925efb2.png